# Are zero-length variable length arrays allowed/well defined?

Tags: c, c99

I'm programming in C99 and use variable length arrays in one portion of my code. I know in C89 zero-length arrays are not allowed, but I'm unsure of C99 and variable length arrays.

In short, is the following well defined behavior?

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char array[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That should not even compile, seeing as `i` is not compile-time constant.

Comment: try compiling that; gcc will come out, punch you, shoot you and steal your car.

Comment: [Guys... this is C99... not C89.](http://ideone.com/NKtfJD)

Comment: @Jashaszun: In C a local array size is not required to be a constant.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: Variable length arrays are allowed in C99...

Comment: @Cornstalks you are invoking undefined behavior and even in c99 *if you lie to the compiler, it will get its revenge*

Comment: @ouah: I'm not trying to lie to the compiler. I just have a variable that ranges from 0 to ~10 that determines how large I need this array to be during each update loop of my program, and I was wondering if variable length arrays had any kind exception to the "no zero length" rule (because if they did, then I wouldn't have to handle the case when my variable is zero separately and explicitly).

Comment: @TheOtherGuy Proof that you're wrong doesn't matter to you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, zero-length arrays are explicitly prohibited by C language, even if they are created as VLA through a run-time size value (as in your code sample).

> **6.7.5.2 Array declarators**
>
> ...
>
> **5** If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant
> expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope,
> it is treated as if it were replaced by *; *otherwise, each time it is
> evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero*.

Comment: Oooo, yay, quotes from the standard. I like those. +1!

Answer (score 2):

Zero-length arrays are not allowed in C. Statically typed arrays must have a fixed, non-zero size that is a constant expression, and variable-length-arrays must have a size which evaluates non-zero; C11 6.7.6.2/5:

> each time it [the size expression] is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero

However, C99 and C11 have a notion of a *flexible array member* of a struct:

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int data[];
};
```

From C11, 6.7.21/18:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a **flexible array member**. In most situations,
>   the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply. However, when a `.` (or `->`) operator has a left operand that is
>   (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that
>   member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same
>   element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed;

Comment: Thanks for the note about the flexible array member. That quote from the standard was really useful!

Answer (score 1):

Zero-length arrays are not allowed in standard C(not even C99 or C11). But gcc does provide an extension to allow it. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

```
 struct line {
   int length;
   char contents[0];
 };

 struct line *thisline = (struct line *)
   malloc (sizeof (struct line) + this_length);
 thisline->length = this_length;
```