# Declaring an array with the size of a global

Tags: c, arrays, coding-style

may i declare an array with a global element in C?
Can i declare with a const type?
It runs on Xcode, however I fear it isn't correct, because glob is not a const type (same thought on static type).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdilib.h>

int glob;
void main (){
    int const con;
    static int stat;
    int arr[glob];
    int arr2[con];
    int arr3[stat];
}
```

In addition, I'm in need of practicing finding mistakes in C code and correcting them for a test (CS student) and could not find a resource for it.

thank you in advance.

Comment: `int const con;` is useless, as the variable(!) is not initialised. C does not have symbolic constants like C++ or Pascal. They are all different languages. And writing `const` after the type is an obsolescence feature; write `const int i = ...;` instead.

Comment: Just to make clear: if you expect the array to resize when the variables change, you are wrong.

Comment: I've changed my mind. This is the real duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18848537/3745896

Comment: `int glob; ...int arr[glob]` is invalid [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17559407/2410359) as `glob` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Globals and statics are automatically initialized to 0 if an initializer isn't provided. The variable `con` local to main however isn't, so its value is undefined.

Comment: What variable has undefined value in this example?

Comment: there is another problem here. You can't declare arrays of size zero. But this is not the question.

Comment: @River - `int const con;`, does it not?

Comment: @EugeneSh. by the C standard this is true, however both GCC and Clang provide extensions allowing zero-length arrays.

Comment: @BingsF GCC just cursed me yesterday for that. So it's fresh on me.

Comment: @BingsF: The question is about C, not some extensions. Note these extensions were to allow some kind of flexible array member in `struct`s and have been superseded by a standard construct since C99. Zero-length VLAs are allowed, though.

Comment: @BingsF I was just clarifying, since you didn't use the actual variable names.

Comment: @River - I see, thanks :)

Comment: Actually `con` is uninitialised, resulting in UB. Even worse, it cannot get a value assigned. `stat` is **not**.

Comment: @Olaf are not `static` variables auto-initialized to `0`?

Comment: @River Yes they are.

Comment: Why should be [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/kGm1N0zv) not legal?

Comment: @River - Oh jeez, brain fart. Fixed.

Comment: Why did he got `-2` Down votes?

Comment: @Michi: Because he fell into the same trap as I did? And because he did not really answer the actual question.

Comment: @Michi - Because you're trying to put 1 thing in a container that holds 0 things.

Comment: @Olaf It could be, but from my side, this  Answer , I don't see whats wrong with it :|

Comment: @BingsF Please exlplain me[What's wrong with this](http://pastebin.com/raw/kGm1N0zv) ?

Comment: @Michi: You access an array outside its boundaries. And array of length `0` has **zero** elements.

Comment: @Olaf Strange that `GCC-5.3` + `Valgrind` [doesn't seems to complain](http://pastebin.com/raw/Dry0RJgu) about this.

Comment: Note: VLA length must be > 0 http://stackoverflow.com/q/17559407/2410359

Comment: @chux: Hmm, I was looking for that, but apparently searched the wrong places. On second thought it sounds logical and (surprisingly:-) consistent.

Answer (score 0):

> may i declare an array with a global element in C?

With C99 and optionally in C11, variable length arrays (VLA) are supported.
[Array length must be more than 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559407/are-zero-length-variable-length-arrays-allowed-well-defined).

```
int glob;
void main (){
  int arr[glob];     // bad array length 0
  int arrX[glob+1];  // OK array length > 0
```

> Can i declare with a const type?

With VLA, yes, it is irrelevant if the type of the array size is `const` or not.

```
// Assume VLAs are allowed
int a[5];         // OK 5 is a constant
const int b = 4;
int c[b];         // OK
int d = 7;
int e[d];         // OK
```

With non-VLA, the array size must be a *constant*.  A variable, `const` or not, is no good.

```
// Assume VLAs not allowed
int a[5];         // OK 5 is a constant
const int b = 4;
int c[b];         // No good, b is not a constant.
```

> In addition, I'm in need of practicing finding mistakes in C code and correcting them for a test

Enable all warnings of your compiler is step 1.